# Calling class constructor without knowing the name of the class in Java

Tags: java, dictionary

This problem easier to understand with code than with words:

```
Map<Integer, Parent> objectMap = new HashMap<Integer, Parent>();

Parent myParent;
Child1 myChild1;
Child2 myChild2;
//A lot more myChilds

myChild1 = new Child1();  //Constructor is expensive, object may not get used
myChild2 = new Child2();  //Constructor is expensive, object may not get used
//Call constructor for all of myChilds

objectMap.put(1, myChild1);
objectMap.put(2, myChild2);
//Place all the myChilds in the objectMap


Parent finalObject;

int number = 1; //This can be any number

finalObject = objectMap.get(number);
```

As you see, I don't know in advance which class will finalObject be. The code works without problem, but here is my question:

How can I avoid calling all the constructors?

As only myChild1 or myChild2 will be used and the constructor methods are quite expensive, I want to only call the one that will actually get used.

Something like

```
finalObject.callConstructor();
```

in the last line

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using google's cache (guava): https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained

Comment: See this tutorial http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/constructors.html

Comment: Where does number come from?

Answer (score 2):

Store the `.class` in the map then use [`Class.newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) when needed?

```
final Map<Integer, Class<? extends Parent>> objectMap = new HashMap<>();
objectMap.put(1, Child1.class);
objectMap.put(2, Child2.class)
// ...

// then later
final Parent aChild1 = objectMap.get(1).newInstance()
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, but I'm getting an IllegalAccessException (eventhough I tried making everything public) and an InstantiationException (but instantiating it with the 'new' works fine). Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Without seing a stacktrace it's hard to tell, maybe you should post a "follow-up" question with a complete [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the `IllegalAccessException`

Answer (score 1):

You can make the constructor of Child objects a dummy constructor and then create another method that does the actual initialization that is expensive.

When you know which child you are going to need then call this method to do the expensive intializations.